# how to read and understand seaborn using joinplot(f1,f2)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

The following code

```
a= np.random.randn(100)
b=np.random.randn(100)
sns.jointplot(a,b)
```

produces

[image]

What is the histogram on the top and right hand side?
And how do I read this graph?

Comment: They show the histogram of the projections of the data to X and Y axis respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The histogram on the top shows the distribution of the variable at the x-axis and the histogram to the right shows the distribution of the variable at the y-axis. 
And the scatter plot is the usual x=a Vs y=b. Hope it helps.

Comment: but when i plot a and b individually, they're different, and don't match.

Comment: It looks perfect. The histogram for the variable on the x-axis would be similar and for the variable on the y-axis, you have to compare it with the mirror image of the joint plot histogram to the histogram of the variable you plotted (Compare it with the y tick values)

Comment: I need to take mirror image of y and x? To get individual histogram?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to understand properly at first.

Comment: Where do we use joint plot usually?

Comment: A good intiutive example is given at the [seaborn documentation](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) where in the first example a jointplot between the tip given in a restaurant and the total bill is presented. The jointplot allows to see a correlation between the two variables: The tendency is that the higher the amount to pay the larger the tip given.

Answer (score 0):

Dataser a's x axis also becomes x axis of the joint plot, database b's x axis becomes y axis of the joint plot. Graph on top and rhs, are same as the individual histogram. The graph is continuous, and changes on bin change, unlike histogram where it may be discontinuous